# How to store the path of a directory from tkinter and then use it later?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have wrote this code until now but it throws an error saying 'TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.TextIOWrapper'. I have tried lot of things like tweaking the path from the txt like - "G:/xyz/xyz", "G://xyz//xyz" or r"G:/xyz/xyz", or r"G://xyz//xyz".

```
import shutil
a = open('file1.txt', 'r')
a1.read()
a.close()

b= open ('file2.txt', 'r')
b1 = b.read()
b.close()

shutil.move(src=a1, dst=b1)
```

Comment: @Popcorm you cant put a text file into a text file. You need to move it into a dir. :D

Comment: Also note the new standard is Pathlib wich is also included in newer python versions in the standard libary. Learn this modul instead.

Comment: and remove the tag tkinter since it has nothing to do with your new question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your Question in the title:
Use filedialog from tkinter to get a path by the user and store it as a variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

root = tk.Tk()

UserPath = fd.askdirectory()
print(UserPath)

root.mainloop()
```

to read the lines with pathlib you need to do it like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('path_to_file')
file = path
with file.open() as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

take a look at this article [here](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/#the-problem-with-python-file-path-handling).

Comment: I found my own mistake I was closing the txt before calling it's variable again and that was the root of my errors. By the way thank you for your support.